# Gradle build not including source/src groovy

Tags: groovy, jar, gradle

I am trying to create a jar from a basic program.

- I have a basic groovy project i.e. src/org...../*.groovy In the root
- I have the following build.gradle

  ```
  apply plugin: 'groovy'
  version = '1.0'

  repositories {
      mavenCentral();
  }

  dependencies
  {
      compile files (fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar']),
          fileTree(dir: 'lib/DocxDep', include: ['*.jar']))
  }

  task buildLabServicesJar(type: Jar) {
  from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
  from {
      configurations.compile.collect {
          it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
      }
      configurations.runtime.collect {
          it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
      }
  }

  manifest {
      attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Lab Services',
          'Implementation-Version': version,
          'Main-Class': 'org.xxx.clarity.ClarityServices'
      }
  }
  ```

Problem is when I run and/or inspec the jar file my sclasses from src/** are not included! (all the dependencies are perfect)

What is the problem here?

**UPDATE**

When I add:
    from files(fileTree(dir: 'src'))
to the task it includes the .groovy files :(

When I add

```
from sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
```

to the task and:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
```

They do not get included :( Can't find any other ways....

Comment: just to clarify one minor issue I see in gradle files all over the world. groovy.srcDir 'src' is _ADDING_ the 'src' directory to the list of source directories (which contains by convention src/main/groovy like mark already pointed out). to _REPLACE_ the convention use groovy.srcDir = ['src']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Final working build.gradle. (thanks all).

```
    apply plugin: 'application'
    apply plugin: 'groovy'

    version = '1.0'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
    }

    dependencies
        {
            compile files (fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar']),
                fileTree(dir: 'lib/DocxDep', include: ['*.jar']))
            compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.6'  //Was missing
        }

    task buildLabServicesJar(type: Jar) {
        from files(sourceSets.main.output)   //Was missing/wrong      
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
        configurations.runtime.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    with jar

    sourceSets.main.groovy {
        srcDirs = [ 'src' ] //Was missing/wrong
    } 

    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Lab Services',
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': 'org.petermac.clarity.ClarityServices'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, Gradle looks for source in `src/main/groovy` when the 'groovy' plugin in applied. You'll need to either restructure your project or configure your [source sets](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html#N12D06) to appropriately reflect your project structure.

Comment: I even tried to add a test groovy file to a package main.groovy and it still does not get included. Building shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: @garethreid: it isn't. You're making life hard for yourself by not following conventions.

Answer (score 1):

referencing `sourceSets.main.output.classesDir` in your jar task means that it will just copy everything from that directory in your jar. The problem is that when you run `gradle buildLabServicesJar` nothing tells gradle that the classes should be compiled first. That's why the directory keeps to be empty and your jar doesn't contain the compiled classes. If you modify your task declaration from

```
task buildLabServicesJar(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    ...
}
```

to

```
task buildLabServicesJar(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output)
    ...
}
```

task autowiring kicks in. task autowiring means that if you declare an output of one task as input to another task (your buildLabServicesJar) gradle knows that it must generate the output first (run the compile task for example).

hope that helps!

Comment: I made that change and the change -> srcDirs = [ 'src/**' ] and now I have no source code (classes or otherwise) in the jar.

Comment: it should be srcDirs = ['src']

Comment: If I do that (['src']) I get the error:Cannot infer Groovy class path because no Groovy Jar was found on class path: configuration ':compile'

Comment: you have to declare a groovy library on your compile classpath. e.g groovy-all

Answer (score -1):

*You must excuse me but I  have recently crossed over from a long life of Microsoft and am still learning. I am surprised by the lack of blogs and example code of basic stuff, what I am doing is so standard....(I will be posting one once/if I figure this out)*

**Note**: Intellij -> Build -> Build Artifacts works perfectly but I would like to move this to Bamboo.

anyway taking into account everyone's ideas, here is my file (and error)

```
     apply plugin: 'groovy'
    version = '1.0'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
    }

    dependencies
    {
        compile files (fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar']),
                fileTree(dir: 'lib/DocxDep', include: ['*.jar']))
    }
    //println "Classes dir: " + sourceSets.main.groovy


    task buildLabServicesJar(type: Jar) {
        from files(sourceSets.main.output)
        //from sourceSets.main.groovy.output
        //from files(fileTree(dir: 'src'))        
        from {
            configurations.compile.collect {
                it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
            }
            configurations.runtime.collect {
                it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
            }
        }

        manifest {
            attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Lab Services',
                    'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': 'org.petermac.clarity.ClarityServices'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            groovy.srcDirs = [ 'src' ]
        }
    }
```

*ERROR:Cannot infer Groovy class path because no Groovy Jar was found on class path: configuration ':compile'*

And if I change src line to:
        srcDirs = [ 'src/**' ]
It builds but leaves out all my source again.